# You are given two numbers a and b. You need to find the power of a that is closest to b

Tags: python

example a is 2 and b is 8 then the result should be 8 (2 raise to 3).
2nd example a is 3 and b is 7  result will be 3 (3 raise to 1)

I have used following function, how can I make it more efficient?

```
def nearestPower(a,b):
    n=1
    for i in range(1, b) :
        if(pow(a,i)<=b):
            n=pow(a,i)
        else:
            break
    return(n)
```

Comment: You need to ask a question, give more details on what it is that you want to do and be more specific.

Comment: If I am able to understand you problem right, you want to find what power should a be raised to that a to the power this number reaches closest to b.

If that's what you want, you just need to make a small change in your code.

if(pow(a,i)<=b): n=i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need the answer, and depending on what you want to do (it seems here that you want the closest lower power of a):

```
from math import log, floor, ceil
def nearestLowerPower(a,b):
    return a ** floor(log(b)/log(a))
def nearestUpperPower(a,b):
    return a ** ceil(log(b)/log(a))
def nearestPower(a,b):
    return a ** round(log(b)/log(a))
```

If you just want an iterative code:

```
def nearestLowerPower(a,b):
    n=1
    while True:
        n *= a
        if n > b:
            return n / a
```

Make sure to assert a >= 1, b >= 1 and work with finite values.

Comment: Thanks for help.